# Setup a multi level cname on Amazon Route 53 (name1.name2.domain.com)

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname, amazon-route53, a-records

I am using Route 53 and I have this problem.

I need a domain name with multiple tiers like: name1.name2.domain1.com to point to domain2.com/more/stuff

I tried adding name1.name2.domain1.com (example) to Route 53 as a cname and it does not work. Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish forwarding through an S3 bucket. If that doesn't work, you can point your domain name to your server and set it up as a parked domain (cpanel). Cpanel will allow you to setup a redirect on that parked domain.